# regexp to get value inside [:(value here):]

Tags: javascript, regex

I  have a following string

```
var str = ":[:{Business AddressId@Business_Address/(:[:(Street Address):] :[:(City):], :[:(State):] :[:(Postal Code):] :[:(Country):])}:]";
```

And I have to  extract  values from inside [:( ):].  so that I  can get an array of values [Street Addess, City,  State, Postal  Code,  Country].  So  far I've got  the following regexp

```
/\[\:\((.*?)\)\:\]\)/g
```

the code

```
var s = str.match(/\[\:\((.*?)\)\:\]\)/g)
console.log(s)
```

returns

```
["[:(Street Address):] :[:(City):], :[:(State):] :[:(Postal Code):] :[:(Country):])"]
```

That's not exactly  what  I need and I'm  not very good  with regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = str.match(/:\(([^)]+)\):/g).map(function(x){
  return x.replace(/:|\(|\)/g,"");
});
console.log(arr); // ["Street Address", "City", "State", "Postal Code", "Country"]
```

The above would do.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the last `\)` from your regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

```
\[:\((.*?)\)\:\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tB9iV6/1)

```
> var str = ":[:{Business AddressId@Business_Address/(:[:(Street Address):] :[:(City):], :[:(State):] :[:(Postal Code):] :[:(Country):])}:]";
> var re = /\[:\((.*?)\)\:\]/g;
> var m;
> var a=[];
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
... a.push(m[1]);
... }
5
> a
[ 'Street Address',
  'City',
  'State',
  'Postal Code',
  'Country' ]
```